# Some data missing when PDF converted to Word or Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, type-conversion, export-to-excel, export-to-word

[image: left side is original pdf; right side is word file]

Hi,

I am using Adobe Acrobat to convert pdf file to word/excel file.
I want to quickly keep data in pdf format to excel format. Since copy/pasting doesn't work because of font errors, I tried using Adobe Acrobat pro version. But as you could see in the picture, some data went missing after converting.

The data that was retained has the font of 'T T 4 B 9t00' or 'T T 4 BAt 00'.
The data that went missing has the font of 'T T 4 B 8t00'.

I am wondering if I could change the font from 'T T 4 B 8t00' to 'T T 4 B 9t00', it might work. But Adobe Acrobat doesn't have these fonts either.

I tried extracting the font using FontForge. But I couldn't extract the fonts.

Any solutions? All I want is to get the data in table format. So far, only some data could be converted successfully.

Comment: You can access the data here @KJ 
https://ceuedu-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/wint-aung_thiha_student_ceu_edu/EWyexeDoXbNDuy_SyMauaqUBLsSGL0TRcIrvNFmLkVNybQ?e=eM8JcX

Comment: Thank you KJ. We had a coup in the country and the guys who produced the pdf are all in jail. There is no way I could go ask an xlsx file from them. :')

Comment: Yes. And the data is election data. I am planning to run some analyses on that.

Comment: I think the question is too broad in the context of SO's purpose. Generally speaking, these types of issues require quite a lot of code and/or quite a lot a manual data manipulation. There are various online tools that offer conversion, but I'm assuming you've already researched and exhausted those?